# Docusaurus change the filename on a downloadble link

Tags: hyperlink, docusaurus

I am using the following markdown to download a file.

`[Grasshopper Definition](bar.gh)`

However, what I get from the browser is a file without extension and weird name.

I did try with
`[Grasshopper Definition](bar.zip)`, and in this case, I get a weirdname.zip file.

anyone knows how to solve the issue?